# EF Core temporary data save (query queuing)

Tags: sql, .net, database, entity-framework-core, data-integrity

I have a windows service which uses EF Core to save data into SQL database. The main requirement for this service is that it works even if database is unavailable. Soo, **if service needs to insert data into database and database is not available it should temporary save it somewhere else and insert them later** (when database is available again).

What would be the best solution for this? I'm thinking about a queue of queries that weren't executed due to database unavailability. Are there any existing solutions for this type of problems? Does EF Core already have some kind of functionality to store data in file and insert them into database, when it becomes available again? Is there maybe any other library to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And if  "somewhere else" is not available.. ?

Comment: @Serg lets suppose that file or at least memory is always available